# Laravel - Where condition is ignored

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 5.2`

I built a query to retrieve some orders.
The query can take up to three filters

1. Order type
2. Order status
3. Keyword (input from the user)

#### Situation

If the user filters the `order type` and/or `order status` it is working fine.

#### Problem

If one filters to get only the `sent` order but inputs `Anna` it would get the `Type B` order which is bad since it is `in progress`

#### Question

I know this caused by something related to the addition of `where` and `orWhere` but I can't find out a solution.

#### Data

```
+------------+--------------+----------+--+
| Order type | Order status | Username |  |
+------------+--------------+----------+--+
| Type A     | Sent         | Jack     |  |
| Type B     | In Progress  | Anna     |  |
+------------+--------------+----------+--+
```

#### Query

```
 if (request()->has('order_type')) {
     $orderLines->where('orders.order_type',  request('order_type'));
 }

if (request()->has('order_status')) {
     $orderLines->where('order_status.name',  request('order_status'));
}

if (request()->has('keyword')) {
    $orderLines->where('order_line_items.last_activity','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
        ->orWhere('users.first_name','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
        ->orWhere('users.last_name','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
        ->orWhere('users.username','like', '%'.request('keyword') 
}
```

Comment: can you check sql log, may be you are getting query in OR condition. `username =anna or order status = sent` according to this the result is fine, the query should be connected with `AND`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (request()->has('keyword')) {
        $orderLines->where(function ($query) {
                $query->orWhere('order_line_items.last_activity','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
                    ->orWhere('users.first_name','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
                    ->orWhere('users.last_name','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
                    ->orWhere('users.username','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass closure to `orWhere` to be able to group the statements in parenthesis. Something like this:

```
$orderLines->where('order_line_items.last_activity','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->orWhere('users.first_name','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
              ->orWhere('users.last_name','like', '%'.request('keyword') .'%')
              ->orWhere('users.username','like', '%'.request('keyword') 
    })
```

Read more in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses). `Parameter Grouping` section.

Comment: It did not fix the problem